# Umbraco: Saving media, not added to cache?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a script that imports some legacy media into Umbraco media library. File gets saved, and is vissible in the backend, and when I access the direct url `mywebsite.com/media/[id]/myfile.pdf` - the file is loaded correct.
But, if I use the media (file or image) on the site, an image for instance, the image does not get shown. If i then find the image in the backend media library, clicks save, and nothing more, it works for that image.

But as there is 1000+ media files, this is not really an option to do manually.
I tried rebuilding the examine indexes, all of them, deleting them, deleting umbraco.config, temp folders etc.

Tried a small script that loops through all media files and saves them again `mediaService.Save(mediaItem)`, but nothing works.

What am I missing?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using the guide from Umbraco, where they import images and saves them one at a time like this:
`foreach(var file in Files){
var media = Services.MediaService.CreateMedia(file.FileName, model.GalleryId, "Image");
Services.MediaService.Save(media);
}`


could it be something with the import script not following this setup? If you have umbraco.tv you can see the setup : https://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/developer/fundamentals/media-api/persisting-changes/

Comment: @elitenet.dk I am doing excatly the same, as the snippet you posted are describing - also, focus points on images are not set (the default value)

Comment: You have to try to rebuild the indexes again. 
Try to stop IIS and delete temp folder, then start again, import images and rebuild indexes with Examine > Index info & tools. People have the same problem when Index is not optimized. (Says "optimized" false if not). Or try to rebuild and then import, the problem should be the index.